# When to use "be" in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-forms, infinitives, future-tense

> We'll ***be*** late!
> We'll late!

> You'll ***be*** so tired in the morning.
> You'll so tired in the morning.

> It will ***be*** very pleasant for you.
> It will  very pleasant for you.
>
> I'll ***be*** all right.
> I'll all right.

To what is ***be*** pointing, in the above sentences?
Are those sentences correct without *be*?

adding 4 sentences which doesn't contain will.

> You're not big enough to be a soldier
>
> How's it feel to be four, Meggie?
>
> He was supposed to be at the forge all day.
>
> I was brought up from my cradle to be a priest

To what is ***be*** pointing, in the above sentences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Will* (or its contracted form *’ll*) is an [**auxiliary verb**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) (your teachers may call this a *helping* or *helper* verb) which expresses only future tense; it must be complemented by a *lexical* verb in the unmarked infinitive form (*be*), which carries the meaning.

1. We're late (*present*) ... We'll be late (*future*)
2. You're so tired (*present*) ... You'll be so tired (*future*)
3. It is very pleasant (*present*) ... It will be very pleasant (*future*)
4. I'm all right (*present*) ... I'll be all right (*future*)

You cannot omit the *be*.

There is also a lexical verb *will*, but it means something different and is conjugated differently (*to will*, *will*, *wills*, *willed*, *willing* instead of *—*, *will*, *will*, *would*, *—*):

> He seemed to will the ball into the net. (*He seemed to score the goal by mental force.*)
>   The European powers willed this pointless war. (*They brought it about deliberately.*)

Comment: Should not it be _will_ also for the third person singular? (That is what I understand from the OALD which says, "third person sing. pres. t. **will**" when speaking of _will_ as verb that means "to want or like.")

Comment: @Kiamlaluno For the *modal auxiliary*, yes; but not for the regular lexical verb: *He wills the ball into the net*. Similarly, the modal has no non-finite forms, but the lexical verb has *to will*, *(has) willed*, *(is) willing*.

Comment: Oh, there are two different _will_: [One](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/will_2) means "to want or like"; [the other one](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/will_3) means (amongs other things) "to use the power of your mind to do something or to make something happen." I was reading the first entry of the dictionary. `:)` (At least, that is the distinction the OALD makes.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes: the first is the oldest sense of the modal; today it is found mostly in fixed phrases like *as you will* and in the *volitive* use of the modal: *if you will do this, I will do that*.

Comment: @StoneyB,Thanks for your comments,can you explain me "be" after "to".

Comment: @AmishAa *Be* is the unmarked infinitive; *to be* is the marked infinitive. For historical reasons, some uses (such as use with the modal verbs *can*, *may*, *will*, *shall*, *must*) require the unmarked infinitive, and other uses (such as those in your second set of examples: complements of *enough* and *suppose*, clauses of purpose, and subject phrases) require the marked version. You have to learn these one by one, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

*Will* is an auxiliary verb, used to express the future. It cannot be used on its own.

Comment: You can use _will_ alone in a sentence similar to "Call it what you will, it's still a problem."

Comment: @kiamlaluno. I know, but that's the lexical _will_, not the auxiliary _will_.

Comment: I think *what you will* is the old volitive sense of the modal: *Call it what he would, he could not persuade them.* *They did for him what he would.*

Comment: @StoneyB. I read it as a lexical verb meaning 'wish, want, desire'.

Comment: The last sentence should be read as "As auxiliary verb, _will_ cannot be used on its own." not "_Will_ can never be used on its own." (I wanted to point out that because learners tend to forget the context in which a sentence is said. `:)`)

Comment: @BarrieEngland But in this sense (as opposed to the distinct lexical verb *to will*) it is formally indistinguishable from the modal, has the same defective conjugation, and is similarly employed as an auxiliary. I think it's the same word.

Comment: @StoneyB. If it is to be seen as an auxiliary in that example, then the clause shows ellipsis. In full it would be _Call it what you will call it_. That’s quite different from the constructions that the OP was proposing, and which I was addressing in my answer.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Wouldn't the clause show exactly the same ellipsis with *want*, except that *want* would require a marked infinitive? - *Call it what you want (to call it)*.

Comment: @StoneyB. It would, but that seems to strengthen the case for _will_ being lexical here rather than modal. Whatever it is, it's no help in answering the OP's question. Just to be clear, in the context of the OP's question, auxiliary _will_ cannot stand alone other than when it occurs in some kind of ellipsis. I really didn't mean to make any more of it than that.

Answer (score 0):

Be is used to show  the existence of something for example "I will be there." It also shows future when used with can, e.g "It cannot be possible for you to do so." Be is used in present, past and future also. In past, it is used as WAS and WERE; in present, it is used as IS, AM and ARE; and in future it can be used with will. BE can be used in passive voice of all tenses as in this sentence.